# Is cross posting in Meta allowed

Tags: discussion

I have made a post on another stack exchange site in the Meta section.

The issue is, what idea could be good for one of the sites, may not be good for the other and as such the question will not get exposed to the full audience if cross posting is not allowed.

So, to save me writing two questions, the post in question is https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3598/is-not-a-real-question-a-misnomer

My questions are:

1. Is cross posting OK
2. Do I need to re-ask the question here as the title of this post has nothing to do with the post I'm citing (I assume so).

Comment: That's why there's Meta.SO which should cover all Stack Exchange and should give you exactly the right coverage

Comment: @IvoFlipse - Thank you, I hadn't realised.